# Is it possible to deploy a client website build with VueJs on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, deployment, production

I was wondering whether or not it i feasible to deploy a VueJs only client website on WordPress, without templates.

If so would you recommend any tutorial for that?
If not or if it is not the best solution, what would you do instead?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[I'm assuming you're using Vue3 here, but it's the same answer for Vue2 really]
You can totally use VueJS as a CDN: https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/production-deployment.html#without-build-tools
It will be less optimal (speed, some limitations etc...) but still doable without having an actual build step in Wordpress.

[The tutorial](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-2) actually can teach you that one, select `HTML` and either `Options` or `Composition` to see how to have the basics to use it on any webpage.
This is what Vue was meant initially, something that you could sprinkle easily on top on an existing codebase, thanks to a CDN.

[petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue) can also be used as a progressive enhancement.

Comment: All right, I'll definitely have a look at these! Thanks for the help. Now assuming I built everything with vue cli, that would not change anything right?